# Laravel Not getting 404 errors

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Hi there I'm having a problem with getting 404 error pages. At the moment all I get is a blank page with no data in it, Below is the code that I have in 3 different pages, I have my missing.blade.php page inside a folder called errors which is in the views folder, can someone tell me if I'm missing something else

// Routes file

```
App::error(function(ModelNotFoundException $e) {
    return Response::view('errors.missing', array(), 404);  
});

App::missing(function($exception) {
    return Response::view('errors.missing', array(), 404);
});
```

// Error 404 Page

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('page-title') @parent
    Error 404
@stop

@section('content')
    <h1>An error occured 404, page missing</h1>
@stop
```

// Controller

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
}
```

Comment: I found that I need to add this line of code to the top of the page  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;

Comment: The next problem is that the page displays the error twice how do I stop that

Comment: I think your Blade template are not compiling. Every Blade tags needs to be on its own line, can you move your `@parent` to its own line and see whether that will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add your error handlers to

app/start/global.php

Comment: Would you know why my error 404 is displaying twice